# Wordpress - After login I just get “Thank you for creating with Wordpress”. Can't see dashboard

Tags: wordpress, authentication, wordpress-theming

I get an error:

```
Thank you for creating with WordPress.
```

In the browser after I login. I can't see the dashboard or any other wordpress page. The website is working fine. I tried clearing the cache in the browser but that didn't work.

This occurred when I was uploading a picture to my Jupiter theme. I accidentally clicked on the reload button and it reloaded but I cannot get back in the dashboard now. I just get this message

Comment: Have you tried contacting your host? Is this before you log in ( as in, when you try to access the login page ) or after you enter your login credentials and log in?

Comment: The problem fixed itself. I guess it was the host/server bug or something.

Answer (score 0):

The problem fixed itself the next day. I'm guessing it was a host bug or server problem.